# App disables and overrides all the keyboard shortcuts

Tags: automator, shortcut

**My OS**: MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

**Name of the app:** Ink2Go

As the title says, an app that I need to use is disabling and overriding all the keyboard shortcuts. In particular:

- it sets its own keyboard shortcuts;
- it **disables** any other key combination which is not an app keyboard shortcuts, therefore it steals all the key combinations.
  (making an annoying sound that tells me that the key combination I am using is "incorrect").

This also prevents me from pressing some keys which would launch some nice Automator macros that I made for this very app.

Do you have any suggestion or just workaround to prevent or circumvent this issue?

Comment: We could do with more info really What OS, what app, which keys it's stealing, etc

Comment: @Tetsujin Added the details you requested in the question. In summary, it is MacOS Sierra 10.12.6, the app is Ink2Go and it steals _all_ the keys, since it overrides the ones which correspond to own app shortcuts and it disables all the others.

Comment: Have you written to the developer of the software with your problem?

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, I will try. I doubt they will be very available to make changes in the code (although I paid for the app), but I will try anyway

Comment: Testing under **macOS Catalina** with version 1.9.1 of **Ink2Go** I could not replicate your described issues. Maybe this has to do with either the version of **Ink2Go** and or the version of **macOS** you are running.